# Minimization of the Unbounded Knapsack with Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am curious if it is possible to modify (or use) a DP algorithm of the **Unbounded Knapsack Problem** to **minimize** the total value of items in the knapsack while making the total weight **at least** some minimum constraint C.

---

A bottom-up DP algorithm for the maximization version of UKP:

```
let w = set of weights (0-indexed)

and v = set of values (0-indexed)

    DP[i][j] = max{ DP[i-1][j], DP[i][j - w[i-1]] + v[i-1] }

for i = 0,...,N and j = 0,...,C

given DP[0][j] = 0 and DP[i][0] = 0

where N = amount of items

and C = maximum weight

DP[N][C] = the maximum value of items for a knapsack capacity of C
```

---

Can we make a minimization UKP ? If not, can anyone offer another solution or technique to solve a problem like this?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: note that it should be `DP[i-1][j - w[i-1]]`, not `DP[i][j - w[i-1]]` in the algorithm above. I tried making the edit but it didn't go through the review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have the new recurrence

```
DP[i][j] (i = 0, j = 0) = 0
DP[i][j] (i = 0, j > 0) = infinity
DP[i][j] (i > 0       ) = min{ DP[i-1][j], DP[i-1][max(0, j - w[i-1])] + v[i-1] },
```

which gives, for each `i` and `j`, the minimum value of items `0..i-1` to make weight at least `j`. `infinity` should be some sufficiently large value such that any legitimate value is smaller than `infinity`.

Comment: Can this algorithm be modified to work with unbounded number of each item?

Comment: @RomanTsopin Change DP[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + v[i-1] to DP[i][j - w[i-1]] + v[i-1].

Comment: Let me preface this: I am learning DP and am not the best at it, so please take this with a grain of salt cause I could be wrong.

I think this recurrence is slightly off. An issue I had when running calculations was if the items were not sorted by weight lowest > greatest this would not calculate correctly.  I was able to correct this by changing a rule of yours. Talking about in paragraph two, with indexing `j - w[-1]` will produce a negative value. If this happens, I set it to infinity and not zero. This way an item that has less weight after it can still be included in the set.

Comment: Amendment to the comment above: After some more testing, you should not set the value to infinity. I think it should be `DP[i-1][j]` instead because we choose not to add the item to the sack, even though we were unable to add it.

Comment: @Matthew It's possible, but reviewing what I wrote (8 years ago, jeez), it seems OK to me. I think code would be helpful for further discussion.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat sure. I sent you an email with it attached.

Comment: @Matthew Ah, the issue is that "knapsack" is a misnomer as I understand the question since there is no upper limit on total weight, only a lower limit. If j < w[i-1] (`votes[i] > j` in the code that you sent me), then we still need to consider taking that item. I'm going to edit the recurrence shortly to be more amenable to implementation.